# Is there any way we can get unique name from linq c#

Tags: c#, linq, unique

I have one id against have multiple same name but other id have different multiple name and I want below expected result from list.

Here I am attaching screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Group by Id, then distinct Name?

Comment: What did you try yourself?

Comment: @YongShun distinct name won't return `"More Name"`

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain I have tried with linq grouping but not get expected result.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain, thanks for the correction, misunderstood the question, get "More Name" instead of [L2, L3, L4].

Comment: Should `L2` really have expected name `"More Name"`? Or is this just a placeholder for let's say `"[L2, L3, L4]"`?

Comment: Please add some code as reference for our solution

Comment: Basically, you need the following: Group by id, check if all elements inside the subarray are the same (if yes: write that name, if not write "More name" or whatever you like)

Comment: ^^ https://dotnetfiddle.net/g16G6r

Answer (score 1):

Just select ,modify value , then distinct

e.g. include mocking class

```
 public class obj{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string name {get;set;}

    public obj(int  i ,string n)
    {
          ID =i; name= n;

    }
    
   }
```

//in main

```
     List<obj> l =new List<obj>();
        l.Add(new obj(1,"L1"));
        l.Add(new obj(1,"L1"));
        l.Add(new obj(2,"L2"));
        l.Add(new obj(2,"L3"));
        l.Add(new obj(2,"L4"));
        l.Add(new obj(3,"L5"));
    //  Console.WriteLine(  l.Where(o=>o.ID==2).GroupBy( m=> new {m.ID, m.name} ).Count() ); got 3 

        var g=  l.Select(   m=> new {ID =m.ID , Name =  ( l.Where(o=>o.ID==m.ID).GroupBy( o=> new { o.ID, o.name} ).Count()>1 )?
        "More Name" :    m.name     }).Distinct(); 

          foreach(var i in g)
          {
              Console.WriteLine( i);

          }
```

// Result

```
{ ID = 1, Name = L1 }
{ ID = 2, Name = More Name }
{ ID = 3, Name = L5 }
```